# What steps of OAuth2 flow does google signin in your browser perform?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client

I'm integrating google signin2 into my website and I have been following the [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) and this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library).

I'm new to OAuth2 and am trying to figure out which steps of the *authorization code* flow is this google api following?

The response returned by google contains a `id_token` and a `access_token`, along with other info about the google user. Am I right the `id_token` is the *authorization code* specified by the standard? What is the role of `access_token` here?

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)
```

According to the standard my app should request a `access_token` from google with `authronization_code`. But the *backend-auth* instruction doesn't say anything about requesting a `access_token`, just verifying `id_token` either in your app or via another google service. Is gsignin-2 not *authorization code* flow at all(implicit)?

If my app just need google signin so user don't have to register their own email+password, ie. I'm not requesting any resources from google outside the browser, which flow should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow I'm following so far is the *Implicit* grant flow, actually the access_token returned by google is empty.

On the server side I have to verify id_token each time, using the javascript version of google-client-api. Since I have to deal with the hustle of verifying id_token for each request on the server, I'm think maybe I should use the *authronization code* flow instead.